# symfony2 assets:install output directory

Tags: symfony

I am trying to change the default "web" directory of symfony to something else for example public_html.

I got most of it working by following the manual here -> http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html

Very last part of that document explains how to change assetic so that assetic:dump will output to the correct directory, so that works, and the website also works.

However the document doesn't seem to explain how to change the output directory of the assets:install command.

When i run this command it still outputs to the web directory.
Does anybody know how to change this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a path parameter to assets:install
But I think in some case better not overriding the directory structure, preferably making a symlink to the web dir.

Comment: Thanks guys, looks like you and Elnut posted pretty much at the same time.
But im gonna give the correct answer to you coz you have less points (hope you dont mind Elnut :) )

But so there is no way to change the "default" output directory of assets:install ?

I won't need it since i will prolly make a symlink like you suggested. but still like to know the anwser to that one.

Comment: also sorry for misspelling your name Elnur :)

Answer (score 5):

`assets:install` requires a parameter telling where to install the assets:

```
app/console assets:install path
```

Just provide your path instead of `web`.

Comment: Isn't there a configuration you can set this permanently? In the composer.json file there is an `"extra": {"symfony-web-dir": "web"} setting. Is this only used for the install command?